# Kasner-Arnold theorem energy role in Needham's "Visual Complex Analysis" (VCA)

Tags: classical-mechanics, orbital-motion, complex-numbers, complex-systems

In "Visual Complex Analysis" (chapter 5.X.6) Tristan Needham writes

> In general, positive energy orbits in either the attractive or repulsive field $F \propto r^A$ map to attractive orbits in the dual field, while negative energy orbits map to repulsive ones.  However, if $-3<A<-1$ (e.g., gravity) then these roles are reversed.  In all cases, zero energy orbits map to force-free rectilinear orbits.

The following notation is used.
Inititial central field: $F \propto r^A$.
Transformation: $z \to z^m$.
Dual central field: $\tilde F \propto \tilde r^{\tilde A}$.
Relationships by [Kasner-Arnold theorem](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=kasner+arnold+theorem): $(A+3)(\tilde A + 3)=4$, $m = (A+3)/2$.

I don't get what is meant by **attractive orbit** and **repulsive orbit**?